# How ida choose arm Thumb/Thumb2

Tags: disassembly, assembly, binary-analysis, arm, thumb2

I load binary file to ida and choose arm cpu.

How can I see if ida choose on arm/arm Thumb2 / arm Thumb?  and how can I change it?

Bytes translate is depend witch arm is it(arm/arm Thumb2 / arm Thumb)

Answer (score 1):

ALT+G switches ARM\Thumb\Thumb2.
I guess IDA uses heuristics to do that, e.g. if you see BX or BLX to an address that doesn't fit 4 bytes then it must be Thumb mode.